# Não estou conseguindo carregar apenas um elemento de uma matriz em um nível mais baixo no mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Pessoa estou tentando puxar apenas um ajudante,
estou fazendo o seguinte,

db.colecao.find(
    { funcionario.nome :  joão },
    { 'funcionario.ajudante.$' : 1  }
);

mas sempre vem todos, já tentei de várias maneiras, obs ali em ajudante poderia ter bem mais e dinâmico

```
{
    empresa : 'nome da empresa',
    funcionario : [
        {
            nome : 'joão',
            ajudante : [
                {
                    nome : manoel,
                    idade : 24
                },
                {
                    nome : joel,
                    idade : 20
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Acho que seria interessante explicar um pouco melhor, esta bemmmm vaga

Comment: Realmente faltou esse trex do código descupas, estou tentando puxar apenas um ajudante Sendo que terá mais de dois e desculpe pelos os erros de ortográfica e de código isso e so um exemplo
estou fazendo o seguinte, 

db.colecao.find(
    { funcionario.nome :  jõao },
    { 'funcionario.ajudante.$' : 1  }
);

mas sempre vem todos, já tentei de várias maneiras

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi você quer retornar somente o(s) ajudantes de algum funcionário.

O find sempre vai retornar um documento da collection, retornando o documento e a estrutura para suportar a tua projeção. Se você executar essa consulta:

```
db.teste.find(
     {"funcionario.nome": "joão", "funcionario.ajudante.nome": 'manoel'}, 
     {"funcionario.ajudante.nome": 1}
)
```

O retorno vai incluir o array com todos os elementos, mas mostrando somente o nome de cada ajudante. Isso acontece porque **na consulta você está pedindo por um documento que tenha um funcionário com nome "joão", que tenha um ajudante com nome "manoel"**.

Se você quer retornar somente o ajudante em questão, precisa usar uma agregação:

```
db.teste.aggregate(
    {$match: {"funcionario.nome" : "joão"}}, 
    {$project: {"funcionario.nome" : 1, "funcionario.ajudante" : 1}}, 
    {$unwind: "$funcionario"}, 
    {$unwind: "$funcionario.ajudante"},
    {$match: {"funcionario.ajudante.nome" : "manoel"}}
)
```

Se você vai buscar os ajudantes de alguém com frequência quem sabe vale a pena colocar eles em uma collection separada, e guardar somente os nomes ou o _id em um array dentro do funcionário.

**Mais importante**: Não faz sentido você guardar a empresa, seus funcionários e ajudantes em um documento só se você não quer recuperar isso de uma vez só do banco.

Dá uma pesquisada sobre a modelagem no mongo, a coisa mais importante é pensar como você vai acessar/modificar os dados.

Comment: valeu amigo muito obrigado

Comment: De nada! Por favor, marque a pergunta como respondida para ficar claro para alguém que estiver buscando.

Comment: sou novo aqui como faço rss

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers :)